# How to ignore white spaces in Java

Tags: java, whitespace

I was wondering how to ignore spaces in Java. This program allows you to enter your first, middle and surname which then outputs your initials. I'm now trying to make it ignore any white spaces. Thanks in advance!

```
        String fullName;
        char firstName;
        char secondName;
        char surname;
        int space1;
        int space2;
                
        System.out.println("Please enter your first name, your second name and your surname: ");
        fullName = kybd.nextLine();
          
        firstName = fullName.charAt(0);
        space1 = fullName.indexOf(" ");
        secondName = fullName.charAt(space1 + 1);
        space2 = fullName.lastIndexOf(" ");
        surname = fullName.charAt(space2 + 1);
            
        System.out.println("Initials: " + firstName + secondName + surname);
```

Comment: Just remove all whitespaces inside `fullName`. For example by `fullName.replaceAll(" ", "")`.

Comment: Currently your question is a bit unclear. Can you give some example inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: Please consider **accepting** an answer if it solved your issue. That helps SO filtering answered from unanswered questions, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

### Explanation

You can implicitly ignore them by just removing them from your input text.

Therefore replace all occurrences with `""` (empty text):

```
fullName = fullName.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

After that call `fullName` won't contain a *whitespace* anymore.

However you'll then get a problem with your logic as you split on *whitespaces*.

---

### Solution

An alternative could be to first `trim` the text (removing **leading** and **trailing** *whitespaces*). Then do your split and after that you can remove all other *whitespaces*:

```
fullName = kybd.nextLine();
// Remove leading and trailing whitespaces
fullName = fullName.trim();

// Bounds
firstSpace = fullName.indexOf(" ");
lastSpace = fullName.lastIndexOf(" ");

// Extract names
String fullFirstName = fullName.substring(0, firstSpace);
String fullSecondName = fullName.substring(firstSpace + 1, lastSpace);
String fullSurname = fullName.substring(lastSpace + 1);

// Trim everything
fullFirstName = fullFirstName.trim(); // Not needed
fullSecondName = fullSecondName.trim();
fullSurname = fullSurname.trim();

// Get initials
firstName = fullFirstName.charAt(0);
secondName = fullSecondName.charAt(0);
surname = fullSurname.charAt(0);
```

---

### Example

Let's take a look at an example input (`_` stands for *whitespace*):

```
__John___Richard_Doe_____
```

We will first `trim` `fullName` and thus get:

```
John___Richard_Doe
```

Now we identify the **first** and the **last** *whitespace* and split on them:

```
First name:  John
Second name: ___Richard
Surname:     _Doe
```

Last we also trim everything and get:

```
First name:  John
Second name: Richard
Surname:     Doe
```

With `charAt(0)` we access the initials:

```
First name:  J
Second name: R
Surname:     D
```

---

### More dynamic

Another more dynamic approach would be to merge all **successive whitespaces** into a **single whitespace**. Therefore you would need to traverse the text from left to right and start *recording* once you see a whitespace, end *recording* if visiting a non-whitespace character, then replace that section by a single whitespace.

Our example then is:

```
_John_Richard_Doe_
```

And after an additional `trim` you can use your regular approach again:

```
John_Richard_Doe
```

---

Or you can use `split(" ")` and then **reject** every **empty** `String`:

```
Iterator<String> elements = Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream(fullName)
    .filter(e -> !e.isEmpty())     // Reject empty elements
    .collect(Collectors.toList())  // Collect to list
    .iterator()                    // Iterator

firstName = elements.next().charAt(0);
secondName = elements.next().charAt(0);
surname = elements.next().charAt(0);
```

Using the example again the `Stream` first consists of

```
"", "", "John", "", "", "Richard", "Doe", "", "", "", "", ""
```

after the filtering it's

```
"John", "Richard", "Doe"
```

---

### Minus Sign

As you said you also want

```
Richard Jack Smith-Adams
```

output `RJS-A`, you can simply split on `-` after splitting on the *whitespace*.

```
Pattern spacePatt = Pattern.compile(" ");
Pattern minusPatt = Pattern.compile("-");
String result = spacePatt.splitAsStream(fullName)  // Split on " "
    .filter(e -> !e.isEmpty())                     // Reject empty elements
    .map(minusPatt::splitAsStream)                 // Split on "-"
    .map(stream ->
        stream.map(e -> e.substring(0, 1)))        // Get initials
    .map(stream ->
        stream.collect(Collectors.joining("-")))   // Add "-"
    .collect(Collectors.joining(""));              // Concatenate
```

Which outputs `RJS-A`.

This approach is a bit more complicated as we need to maintain the information of the sub-streams, we can't just `flatMap` everything together, otherwise we wouldn't know where to add the `-` again. So in the middle part we are indeed operating on `Stream<Stream<String>>` objects.

Comment: I'm unsure where to put that code, can you please tell me?

Comment: @Smithy98 Yeah, I edited the code, is it clearer now?

Comment: It does make sense but I get errors for the 2 lines of code under "Bounds". It says "possible lossy conversion from int to char". I've declared them as chars, not an int though..

Comment: @Smithy98 Oh, yeah they should be `int` **not** `char`. The method returns the **position** at which this character occurs, not a **character**.

Comment: Of course! Thanks so much for the help, it works now. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Smithy98 You're welcome! I've edited the answer again, check out the last example using `Stream`s, I really like it, it's also very compact.

Comment: Thanks. I also want it to include hyphenated names, e.g. Smith-Adams. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @Smithy98 So you want to treat `Smith-Adams` as `Smith Adams`? Just replace every such character before with a *whitespace*: `fullName = fullName.replaceAll("-", " ")`. You can also use **regex** here to include more than just `-`, just as reference.

Comment: No, sorry, I want it to include both of the hyphenated names as one initial.     For example, if I entered Richard Jack Smith-Adams, it would be displayed as RJS-A

Comment: @Smithy98 Mh.. Before picking the initial of `fullXYName` you can then simply do the same procedure with `-`, just split on it. I've edited the answer by adding a `Stream` version again.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after here is the [split method in String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

Which you could use like this:

```
String fullName = "John Alexander Macdonald";
String[] split = fullName.split(" "); // ["John", "Alexander", "Macdonald"]
```

The other thing you might want is the [trim method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) which removes spaces from the front and the back of a string.

```
String withSpaces = " a b c ";
String trimmed = withSpace.trim(); // "a b c"
```

Comment: The user has to input their own name so it isn't hardcoded

Comment: You can still do `fullName.split(" ");` My hardcoded string was just for an example.